# How to add email message body in opensearch dashboard

Tags: opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

we are trying to send email notifications using few filters.the requirement is we need to add the error description in the email body. we didnt find any solution in the OpenSearch dashboard monitoring document. could you please help me how to add the message body in the email notification of opensearch dashboard triggers.